# Storing dynamic text in Selenium

Tags: testing, selenium, automation

I'm new to Selenium and had the following question about storing dynamic text...

In our web application, when a function is performed (i.e. transfer), a confirmation message is displayed (i.e. "function is completed.  The reference number is #12345".  The ref number is then displayed in a list with other ref numbers on another page.  As part of my test, after the ref. number is generated, I would like to select from the list the ref number that was just generated. 
Example
1 create item.
2 confirmation message displays
3 save ref number
4 navigate to other page which contains list of ref #s
5 select item from list that was just created (select using ref #)

Question: How do I save the ref number from the confirmation message so that I have Selenium select that number from the list of ref #'s?

Thanks,
D

Comment: what language are you creating your selenium tests in?

Comment: Just started, so using default  (HTML) right now but I plan to use Python later on...

Answer (score 1):

Find out the identifier (CSS/XPath/etc.) of the UI element that displays the reference number, and then use the relatively getText() command. In Java,

```
String text = selenium.getText("your_identifier");
```

Comment: hmmm. True.  I'll try it out with Python with similar commands.  Thanks.